# Change Select tag border color by value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Color of select fields in class "Form" do not change to red when its clicked and left as it is without selecting the option. it should check if the option has value other than 1 and border should remain as it is.

```
$(".Wrapper .Right_Section .Form select").on('blur',function(){ 
  if( $(this, 'option:selected').val() == 0 ){
    $(this).css('border-color', '1px solid #C80000');    
  }
  else if ($(this).val() > 0) {
    $(this).css('border-color', '1px solid #BDC7BC');   
  } 
});
```

Here `.Wrapper .Right_Section .Form` are divs are within each other and select tag is in `.Form div`.

Comment: Change `border-color` to `border`, or remove the `1px solid` portion from your style.

Comment: well that is causing the border to vanish all together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two problem.

1. In [`jQuery(selector [, context ])`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/), first parameter is selector and second is context.
2. You should write color string in second parameter of [`.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/).

```js
$(".Wrapper .Right_Section .Form select").on('blur',function(){ 
  if ( $('option:selected', this).val() == 0 ){
    $(this).css('border-color', '#C80000');     
  }
  else if ($(this).val() > 0) {
    $(this).css('border-color', '#BDC7BC');    
  }
});
```

```js
$("select").on('blur',function(){ 
  if ($('option:selected', this).val() == 0)
    $(this).css('border-color', '#C80000');     
  else if ($(this).val() > 0)
    $(this).css('border-color', '#BDC7BC');   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm really new to jQuery. But wouldn't we need 'this' to guide it to the tag currently being cheked and then the option of that tag will be checked?

Comment: Thanks man straight and simple. but can you explain the logic please as to why this needs to be after the option

Comment: @Faran52 You can read [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/) to better understanding. However `JQuery()` and `$()` is same and the first parameter of `JQuery()` is selector as you write `$("div")`. second parameter as default is `document` but you can change it. Like `$("div", this)`.

Comment: Or `this.style.borderColor = '#CB0000;'`

Answer (score 4):

Please check this.
Remove `border-color` and add `border` because you are specifying all border properties.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select").blur(function(){
    //alert($(this).val());
    if(parseInt($(this).val())<=0){
      $(this).css("border","solid 1px red");
    }
    else{
      $(this).css("border","solid 1px blue");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just added it in case you want to use it. Please accept and upvote if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check on `$(this).val() != ""` this is the first thing, secondly you have to adapt your selector `$(".Wrapper .Right_Section .Form select")` maybe can use something like `$("form select")` ...
Otherwise I suggest to a class required on css with `.required-error{border : Apx solid #C80000;}` then you may use `$(this).addClass('required-error');` or `$(this).removeClass('required-error');`

Answer (score -1):

```js
$("select").on('blur',function(){ 
  if ($('option:selected', this).val() == 0)
    $(this).css('border-color', '#C80000');     
  else if ($(this).val() > 0)
    $(this).css('border-color', '#BDC7BC');   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```